# I try to implement curl script for request to server but it is not working

Tags: c++, http, curl

I have a curl script:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/txt" -X POST --data-binary "@name_file.txt" -g "https://ya.com/file.txt" > .\out.txt
```

I can use it via console ant it works good.

I implement this script in visual studio on C++:

```
auto curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(path_to_file.c_str(), "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ya.com/file.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list); // - H

    std::string data_for_send = data_for_send_arr.c_str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, data_for_send.size());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data_for_send.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackfunction);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK) AfxMessageBox(_T("error"));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    fclose(fp);
}

size_t callbackfunction(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata)
{
    FILE* stream = (FILE*)userdata;
    if (!stream)
    {
        printf("!!! No stream\n");
        return 0;
    }

    size_t written = fwrite((FILE*)ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
```

i also i need to tell that at one moment i use async call:
async(func_curl_1, data_1);
async(func_curl_2, data_2);

each function create curl and do request for server at the same time.

but this script do not work. it work one time from seven request
server returned for me empty file or broken file.

i do not know why...

Comment: This sample code is incomplete (e.g. missing `data_for_send_arr`, includes, functions...). Present a [mcve] please. You should already have one from your testing/debugging.

Comment: _"If you did not already call curl_global_init, curl_easy_init does it automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since curl_global_init is not thread-safe, and it may result in resource problems because there is no corresponding cleanup."_ https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your settings CURLOPT_VERBOSE
i.e.

```
/* ask libcurl to show us the verbose output */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

and investigate output